# Why is output int?

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

Why is the main method not calling the first method?

```
public class Test {           

    public static void printValue(byte...b) {  
        System.out.println("long");  
    }  

    public static void printValue(int i, int j, int k) {  
         System.out.println("int");  
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {  
        byte b = 9;  
        printValue(b,b,b);  
    }  
}
```

Why is the output `int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While choosing the most appropriate method, compiler will first prefer to do *Widening*, then *Boxing*, and at the end, if all fails, *Var-args*. In your case, it will widen all the `bytes` to `ints` to get the matching method, with 3 `int` type parameters. 
For more details on this, see [JLS §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

Comment: Why would the compiler prefer to do that before choosing the right method?

Comment: Can you explain about widening and boxing in this case?

Comment: There's a general recommendation by Joshua Bloch to avoid varargs as much as you can. In this case you wouldn't have suffered this "unexpected" behavior.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This is because, *widening* was already there from Java 1, and Boxing and Var-args were added in Java 5. It seems like the rational is to keep the exisiting code work as it is, after addition of new features.

Comment: @RohitJain That link what I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: @MarounMaroun The right method according to *who*? because according to the rules, that's the right method.

Comment: @Raj There is no boxing in this case. Widening is from `byte` to `int` type for all three arguments.

Comment: @Darkhogg Of course according to the *compiler*.. It doesn't really care about what we think ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun The compiler is just a set of rules, that usually drives us crazy in the corner cases like this where *intuition* spits an specially-cased set of extra rules but the compiler doesn't

Comment: Note that the preference of widening over varargs is desired in cases where you are overloading varargs methods with fixed-args-methods for performance.

Answer (score 1):

In other way, you have overloaded `printValue` method. Now while making the call `printValue(b,b,b);` compiler can't find a `printValue` signature which takes `byte` as argument type and have 3 arguments but it can find that `printValue` has a overload which takes 3 parameter but accepts type `int` and `byte` can be implicitly casted to `int`.

so it ends up calling the method overload `printValue(int i, int j, int k)`

Answer (score 1):

while calling a method compiler first check the method name,parameter lists with datatype to match exactly, like method **overloading**.

**if compiler doesn't get exact match for method, it looks for the best match. in your case it first check the method   printValue() having three parameters.**

it chooses public static void printValue(int i, int j, int k) method because -

-compiler doesn't get the exact matced method.

**-it looks for appropriate match like byte->int , char -> int , int->long can be done explicitly.**(widening) or autoboxing.** smaller data type can be converted into larger data type value. so it calls printValue(int i, int j, int k).**
-your passed value can be easily converted into integer. 9- is also byte,char, integer data type value.